# Are UI elements initiated in Fragment or FragmentActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am porting Activity-type app to Fragments-type app. I am a bit confused where I am supposed to initiate UI elements of the fragment.

For example, if I initiate a button from `Fragment` class in `FragmentActivity` class, I **get no error**.

```
    btnOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_one);
```

But, if I try to initiate `onClick` listener, then **I get error** of type `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Then again, I cannot find method `findViewById` in the `Fragment` class.

Am I really forced to initiate in `FragmentActivity` and to specify listeners in `Fragment`?

Comment: Fragments use the `onCreateView` [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView)

Comment: @A--C Yes, it's more or less the same as onCreate. Are you suggesting to create listeners in `onCreateView` or ALL initialization to execute there?

Comment: I would do that, or use `getView()` when needed. Also, all your initialization for the Fragment's View should be done there. Usually it just involves inflating the view, but I don't see why creating listeners would be frowned upon.

Comment: @A--C It's not the issue with `onClick`, but the fragment is supposed to do something which is possible only inside the Activity. Is there a way to use `getView` or similar method to fetch Fragment's `View` (UI element) from inside `FragmentActivity`?

Comment: Make your Fragment an inner static class and just call the outer class's method. That might work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You initiate your button in the fragment usually. An example would be:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, container, false);

        Button yourbutton = (Button) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        yourbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                     //Do your thing
               }
        }

        return fragmentView;
}
```

Comment: Normally, we initialize components in the onCreate() method in Activities but is it possible or necessary to initialize them in the onCreate() method in fragments?

Comment: In case of fragments, onCreate runs before onCreateView, where you inflate the layout xml (if you have any). In case of an activity, you inflate in onCreate, so the first possible place to init your components is in onCreateView, as in the example code above. However you can init later in onAcrivityCreated, which runs after the parent activity's onCreate (if it makes any sense in your application's case to delay).